# How to find nearest next/previous double value (numeric_limits::epsilon for given number)

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

The title is quite self-explanatory, input is given double value, and I want to add/substract the smallest amount possible.

Comment: Would `double next = value + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() work` ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @rve: At some point that stops increasing the value (has no effect), because the value you began with is a better approximation of the new value, which can't be precisely stored. So you get stuck in a loop of not quite reaching the next number.

Comment: @rve, no, as it is epsilon for double with value 1, the epsilon gets bigger and bigger with higher numbers, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `nextafter`, which is available if your compiler implements C99's math functions (i.e., C++11 and above). This function (and its various overloads) can be described as:

```
double nextafter(double value, double target);
```

It will move from `value` **in the direction of** `target` by the smallest possible amount (typically by tweaking the bit representation of the float). If `value` is already at `target`, this does nothing.

If `target` is greater than `value` this will increment `value` by the smallest possible amount. If `target` is less than `value` this will decrement `value` by the smallest possible amount.

Common usage is to pass either `DBL_MAX` or `INFINITY` as the target to increase the minimal amount (or, the negation of them to decrease the minimal amount).

The choice between `DBL_MAX` and `INFINITY` depends on what you want to do at the boundary - `nextafter(DBL_MAX, DBL_MAX) == DBL_MAX`, but `nextafter(DBL_MAX, INFINITY) == INFINITY`.

And yes, it's poorly named. See also [`nextafter` and `nexttoward`: why this particular interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063370/nextafter-and-nexttoward-why-this-particular-interface).

---

```
#include <cfloat> // DBL_MAX
#include <cmath> // std::nextafter

double x = 0.1;

// Next representable number **after** x in the direction of DBL_MAX.
// (i.e., this is larger than x, and there is no double between it and x)
double xPlusSmallest = std::nextafter(x, DBL_MAX); 

// Next representable number **before** x in the direction of -DBL_MAX.
// (i.e., this is smaller than x, and there is no double between it and x)
double xMinusSmallest = std::nextafter(x, -DBL_MAX);
```

Even if your compiler doesn't support it, it probably has an instrinsic for it. (MSVC has had `_nextafter` since 2005, for example. GCC probably implements it as standard.)

If your compiler doesn't support it but Boost is available to you, you can do this:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/next.hpp>
#include <cfloat> 

double x = 0.1;

double xPlusSmallest = boost::math::nextafter(x, DBL_MAX); 
double xMinusSmallest = boost::math::nextafter(x, -DBL_MAX);
```

And if none of those work for you, you'll just have to crack open the Boost header and copy it.

Comment: What about the previous representable value?

Comment: @pmor The second parameter is a target, specifying direction, so you can just negate it. (Yes, this means the "next after" can go to the number before...it's not well named.) I realized this answer was a bit light on the details, let me know if this update clarifies.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a very dirty trick that isn't actually legal and only works if your platform uses IEEE754 floats: The binary representation of the float is ordered in the same way as the float value, so you can increment the binary representation:

```
double x = 1.25;

uint64_t * const p = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&x);

++*p;   // undefined behaviour! but it gets the next value

// now x has the next value
```

You can achieve the same effect entirely legally by doing the usual binary copy gymnastics to obtain a proper `uint64_t` value. Make sure to check for zero, infinity and NaN properly, too.

Comment: Will this handle correctly mantissa overflow ? What happens if the binary representation is .111111111 * 2^k ? Does it give .00000000 * 2^{k+1} ?

Comment: "binary representation of the float is ordered in the same way as the float value" is common yet not specified by the language.  Real examples have existed.

Answer (score -4):

How about:

```
x += fabs(x) * std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
```

Comment: Supposing you meant to add `::min()`, this won't work for denormalized numbers, and needs a proof for the regular case. What does IEEE 754 guarantee about ULPs under multiplication and addition? I would think that numbers `1.5*2^n ≤ x < 2^n+1` would round up to double the desired epsilon after the multiplication, although it should work with a fused multiply-add.

Comment: Whoops--just forgot to write epsilon...fixed now

Comment: @DrewHall I also meant `epsilon`, not removing the downvote since the points still stand…

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  I believe you're correct on both counts--it really depends on how rigorous the OP is trying to be.  I'd call this the "70% solution" that would be good enough for most purposes.  YMMV...

Answer (score -5):

```
#define FLT_MIN         1.175494351e-38F        /* min positive value */
#define FLT_MAX         3.402823466e+38F        /* max value */
#define DBL_MIN         2.2250738585072014e-308 /* min positive value */
#define DBL_MAX         1.7976931348623158e+308 /* max value */
```

http://xona.com/2006/07/26.html

Comment: I think the OP wants to know the smallest possible *difference* between two float/double numbers, not the min/max values.

Comment: but it also shows how the minimum values are less than the ones stored in float.h file

Comment: @AlexZ K. Then it depends on the FPU. The link I gave shows the precision to which FPU can process. And so I feel that the minimum difference can be the minimum positive value that can be processed

Comment: dipal saluja: No it is not, as the precision of floating point numbers decreases with size.

Comment: @dipalsaluja : Consider [this program](http://ideone.com/YgsJg). DBL_MIN is **not** the minimum difference between an arbitrarily-chosen value and its immediate successor.

Comment: @Marwin: I would like to explore it in greater depth...Please share a link regarding this...Thanks!!

Comment: @Robᵩ: ya as i said http://xona.com/2006/07/26.html shows how values less than the ones stored in float.h are possible :)