# Is 1.0 a valid output from std::generate_canonical?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I always thought random numbers would lie between zero and one, **without `1`**, i.e. they are numbers from the half-open interval [0,1). The [documention on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/generate_canonical) of `std::generate_canonical` confirms this.

However, when I run the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng;

    std::seed_seq sequence{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    rng.seed(sequence);
    rng.discard(12 * 629143 + 6);

    float random = std::generate_canonical<float,
                   std::numeric_limits<float>::digits>(rng);

    if (random == 1.0f)
    {
        std::cout << "Bug!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the following output:

```
Bug!
```

i.e. it generates me a perfect `1`, which causes problems in my MC integration. Is that valid behavior or is there an error on my side? This gives the same output with G++ 4.7.3

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.c && ./a.out
```

and clang 3.3

```
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.c && ./a.out
```

If this is correct behavior, how can I avoid `1`?

**Edit 1**: G++ from git seems to suffer from the same problem. I am on

```
commit baf369d7a57fb4d0d5897b02549c3517bb8800fd
Date:   Mon Sep 1 08:26:51 2014 +0000
```

and compiling with `~/temp/prefix/bin/c++ -std=c++11 -Wl,-rpath,/home/cschwan/temp/prefix/lib64 test.c && ./a.out` gives the same output, `ldd` yields

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff39d0d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /home/cschwan/temp/prefix/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f123d785000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000317ea00000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/cschwan/temp/prefix/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f123d54e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000317e600000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000317e200000)
```

**Edit 2**: I reported the behavior here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63176

**Edit 3**: The clang team seems to be aware of the problem: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18767

Comment: That seems wrong, indeed.

Comment: Test it on g++, clang and VS2013. Only VS2013 got it right Clang and g++ are generating 1.0. Seems like a double bug both gcc and Clang are wrong.

Comment: The compiler has nothing to do with the generated number, the stdlib is important - I'm guessing you're using libstdc++ for GCC and Clang. If you can, try libc++.

Comment: Oh thats interesting. Whats the output of VS2013? How is different from GCC/clang?

Comment: Forget what I said, VS2013 generates values >> 1.0.

Comment: @Xeo: I didn't, but even with libc++ it is the same.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with GCC. As Xeo said, it's not the compiler per se, but the standard library. Try to update it. My rather recent version doesn't have this bug.

Comment: @Niall It is perfectly accurate. A simple `if ( random == 1.0f ) { std::printf("Bad\n"); }` would have been enough.

Comment: @David Lively `1.f == 1.f` in all cases (what all cases are there? I don't even seen any variables in `1.f == 1.f`; there's only one case here: `1.f == 1.f`, and that is invariably `true`). Please don't spread this myth further. Floating point comparisons are always exact.

Comment: It seems that both GCC and Clang got it wrong and produce 1.0 and this is a bug that should be reported. For completeness sake, I tried the code posted by the OP with VS2013 I get numbers that are >> 1. Searched a little bit and found that this is a bug for VS2013 that's still active ([bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811611/std-generate-canonical-does-not-generate-random-number-in-range-0-1)).

Comment: Clearly you don't understand how floating point numbers work.

Comment: @DavidLively: No, it's not. The comparison is always exact. It's your operands that may not be exact _if_ they are calculated and not literals.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong (not an expert) but wouldn't there be be a range of values (between the last representable value before 1.0 and 1.0) which would be left out unless occasionally 1.0 is output as the nearest rounded value? I mean the range [1.0 - epsilon, 1.0). Would that not sometimes round down to (1.0 - epsilon) and other times round up to 1.0?

Comment: @Galik any positive number below 1.0 is a valid result. 1.0 is not. It's as simple as that. Rounding is irrelevant: the code gets a random number and doesn't perform any rounding on it.

Comment: Hm, the GCC from git (updated a few days ago) gives the same, but I am not sure I am using the newest libstdc++. Is it enough to prefix `./a.out` with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to the corresponding path?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, some clarity, thanks.

Comment: @cschwan: Could be, but check with `ldd`.

Comment: @DavidLively he's saying that there is only one value that compares equal to 1.0. That value is 1.0. Values close to 1.0 don't compare equal to 1.0. It doesn't matter what the generation function does: if it returns 1.0 it will compare equal to 1.0. If it doesn't return 1.0 it will not compare equal to 1.0. Your example using `abs(random - 1.f) < numeric_limits<float>::epsilon` checks if the result is *close to 1.0*, which is totally wrong in this context: there are numbers close to 1.0 that are valid results here, namely, all those that are less than 1.0.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes Okay I accept that. But to clarify my point I was talking about the inevitable rounding that happens within the random number generating algorithm due to hardware limitations on representing the actual number. It means that numbers extremely close to 1.0 either can not be represented at all or else are rounded down to (1.0 - epsilon) giving an over-representation of those values. Or, at least, that's how it seems to me.

Comment: @Galik Yes, there will be trouble implementing that. But that trouble is for the implementer to deal with. The user must never see a 1.0, and the user must always see an equal distribution of all the results.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Okay, I am apparently having a Monday, on Thursday. I am often wrong. This may be one of those times. I'll deleting my earlier comments as they appear to be misleading.

Comment: Should the title of this question be "is 1.0 a valid output from std::generate_canonical"? As it stands it's rather ill-posed.

Comment: Well, it seems to attract a lot of viewers ;) - but yes, you're right.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The problem is in mapping from the codomain of `std::mt19937` (`std::uint_fast32_t`) to `float`; the algorithm described by the standard gives incorrect results (inconsistent with its description of the output of the algorithm) when loss of precision occurs if the current IEEE754 rounding mode is anything other than round-to-negative-infinity (note that the default is round-to-nearest).

The 7549723rd output of mt19937 with your seed is 4294967257 (`0xffffffd9u`), which when rounded to 32-bit float gives `0x1p+32`, which is equal to the max value of mt19937, 4294967295 (`0xffffffffu`) when that is also rounded to 32-bit float.

This is recognized as a defect in the standard, tracked as [LWG issue 2524](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2524). The paper series [P0952](https://wg21.link/P0952) (currently [P0952R2](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0952R2.html)) proposes fixing the specification by adopting rejection sampling, which would significantly change behavior by altering the number of calls to the underlying URBG.

The standard could ensure correct behavior if it were to specify that when converting from the output of the URNG to the `RealType` of `generate_canonical`, rounding is to be performed towards negative infinity; this would give a correct result in this case.  As QOI, it would be good for libstdc++ to make this change.

With this change, `1.0` will no longer be generated; instead the boundary values `0x1.fffffep-N` for `0 < N <= 8` will be generated more often (approximately `2^(8 - N - 32)` per `N`, depending on the actual distribution of MT19937).

I would recommend to not use `float` with `std::generate_canonical` directly; rather generate the number in `double` and then round towards negative infinity:

```
    double rd = std::generate_canonical<double,
        std::numeric_limits<float>::digits>(rng);
    float rf = rd;
    if (rf > rd) {
      rf = std::nextafter(rf, -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity());
    }
```

This problem can also occur with `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>`; the solution is the same, to specialize the distribution on `double` and round the result towards negative infinity in `float`.

Comment: If the output of the generator is truncated to 24 bits and divided by 16777216f, the result should be one of 16777216 equally-likely values.  If the generator isn't truncated to 24 bits, individual values above 0.5 will occur about twice as often as those between 0.25 and 0.5.

Comment: @supercat no truncation occurs; the output of the URNG is cast to the target type and then divided by the URNG's max, also cast to the target type. The facility `generate_canonical` isn't aiming for individual values in [0, 1) to occur equally often; it's aiming for uniform distribution.

Comment: I would think the best uniform distribution for `float` would be computed by taking a 23-bit number, adding 0.5, and dividing by 8388608.  For any `float` values 1.0 <= a <= b <= 2.0, the expected average of returned numbers in the range (a-1.0,b-1.0) would be precisely (a+b-2)/2.  I'm not sure how well that property can be upheld if one doesn't truncate the random number generator before division, no matter which rounding mode one uses.

Comment: @supercat yes, I see - e.g. for a=1.25, b=1.75, all the values between 0.25 and 0.5 and between 0.5 and 0.75 would occur, with the former being twice as dense so occurring half as often, but with an upward bias of 2^-25 as a result in the lower half-range. Your suggestion would definitely have better statistics.

Comment: I've noticed a tendency sometimes for people to assume that the precision of a range-bounded number should be relative to its magnitude, rather than to the magnitude of the range.  Some "sine" functions, for example, go out of their way to yield absurd levels of "precision" at angles where the sine is nearly zero.  If there were a function to compute 1-cos(x), such a function could be meaningfully precise to within 1E-32, but for values of x near pi, any precision of sin(x) finer than about 1E-16 is meaningless.

Comment: If code is expecting a range to be uniformly distributed from 0 to 1 and can deal with a gap of 1/16777216 between values greater than 0.5, it should be able to deal with such a gap anywhere in the range.  Further, the benefits of eliminating bias would in most applications outweigh any harm caused by doubling the gap to 1/8388608.  In some rare cases there could be value to a random method which would return 23 or 24 meaningful bits of mantissa regardless of the magnitude of the value, but that should be handled by using an exponential distribution to select the magnitude, ...

Comment: ...and then setting the mantissa by multiplying a 1/2^n fraction by a integer from 8388608 to 16777215.

Comment: What does QOI stand for?

Comment: @user quality of implementation - all the things that make one conformant implementation better than another e.g. performance, behavior in edge cases, helpfulness of error messages.

Comment: @supercat: To digress a bit, there actually are good reasons to try to make sine functions as accurate as possible for small angles, e.g. because small errors in sin(x) can turn into large errors in sin(x)/x (which [occurs quite often](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) in real-world calculations) when x is close to zero. The "extra precision" near multiples of π is generally just a side effect of that.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: For sufficiently small angles, sin(x) is simply x.  My squawk at Java's sine function relates to is with angles that are near multiples of pi. I would posit that 99% of the time, when code asks for `sin(x)`, what it *really* wants is the sine of (π/Math.PI) times x. The people maintaining Java insist that it's better to have a slow math routine report that the sine of Math.PI is difference between π and Math.PI than to have it report a value which is slightly less, notwithstanding that in 99% of applications it would be better...

Comment: ...to scale up the argument by a factor of π/Math.PI, such that an argument of Math.PI would yield a sine of zero.  If code wishes to compute the sine of an angle expressed in degrees, multiplying by Math.PI/180.0 before performing argument reduction to a range of +/-45 degrees will lose some precision, but the resulting precision would still be acceptable.  In such cases, however, the extra code the JVM added to make the results "precise" in fact makes the results less accurate than they would be in the absence of such code.

Comment: @supercat: (double)π/Math.PI == 1.0. (The bits that make the ratio useful would get lopped off.)  Aside from that, though, an implementation of a well-known standard math function shouldn't try to guess intent.  When i ask for `sin(x)`, i want `sin(x)`. I'd prefer not even losing precision to rounding errors. But at the very least, i should get sin(exactly x). Assumptions about `Math.PI` throw off the result if i didn't multiply by `Math.PI`. It's valid and useful for some other function to make such assumptions, but it shouldn't misrepresent itself as the true sine function.

Comment: @cHao: Can you offer up *any realistic, non-contrived, scenario* in which, a slower implementation of sin(x) which always returns a value which is within 0.75 lsb of the sine of the exact value of x would be more useful than a faster one which always returns a value that is within 0.5lsb of the exact sine of some value which is within 0.5lsb of x?  For that matter, in what non-contrived scenarios would the value 884279719003555/281474976710656 be computed without rounding errors?

Comment: @supercat: I didn't say i don't tolerate rounding errors; they're pretty much inevitable unless you only ever divide by powers of two.  But of course, i would prefer they not exist, and unless performance is actually an issue, i'd prefer a slow, accurate result over a fast, sloppy one.  As for the usefulness of being sloppy, honestly, i haven't looked too deeply into it.  I just know that whenever possible, when i ask for X, i would very much like to be able to trust that i got X and not something that kinda sorta resembles X.

Comment: @ecatmur Suggestion; update this post to mention that `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>` suffers from the same problem as a consequence of this.  (So that people searching for uniform_real_distribution will have this Q/A come up).

Comment: @ecatmur, I'm not sure why you want to round towards negative infinity. Since `generate_canonical` should generate a number in the range `[0,1)`, and we're talking about an error where it generates 1.0 occasionally, wouldn't rounding towards zero be just as effective?

Comment: @MarshallClow yes, round towards zero would also work fine here.

Comment: @T.C. Is this issue fixed now?

Comment: "Without this change, not only will 1.0 be generated occasionally, but 0.0 will be generated half as often as it should." I don't think this is true. The issue here is floating-point rounding error, and at the 0-end there's no rounding involved; everything is exact.

Comment: @T.C. yes, you're right, and the final division by `0x1p+32` is also exact; the space that becomes 1.0 is stolen from the boundary values `0x1.fffffep+N` for `24 <= N < 32`. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Late to the part, but: Would a trivial wrapper which simply discards 1.0 and tries again also skew the distribution?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think it's slightly worse; if I've calculated correctly, by rounding down, the values that would become `1.0f` get distributed with mean 2/3, whereas with rejection sampling they get distributed with mean 1/2. So the skew is 3/2 as great with rejection.

Answer (score 40):

According to the standard, `1.0` is not valid.

> #### C++11  §26.5.7.2 Function template generate_canonical
>
> Each function instantiated from the template described in this section 26.5.7.2 maps the result of one or more invocations of a supplied uniform random number generator `g` to one member of the specified RealType such that, if the values g<sub>i</sub> produced by `g` are uniformly distributed, the instantiation’s results t<sub>j</sub> , **0 ≤  t<sub>j</sub> < 1**, are distributed as uniformly as possible as specified below.

Comment: +1 I can't see any flaw in the OP's program, so I'm calling this a libstdc++ and libc++ bug... which itself seems a little unlikely, but there we go.

Answer (score -3):

I just ran into a similar question with `uniform_real_distribution`, and here's how I interpret the Standard's parsimonious wording on the subject:

The Standard always defines math functions in terms of *math*, never in terms of IEEE floating-point (because the Standard still pretends that floating-point *might not* mean IEEE floating point). So, any time you see mathematical wording in the Standard, it's talking about *real math*, not IEEE.

The Standard says that both `uniform_real_distribution<T>(0,1)(g)` and `generate_canonical<T,1000>(g)` should return values in the half-open range [0,1). But these are *mathematical* values. When you take a real number in the half-open range [0,1) and represent it as IEEE floating-point, well, a significant fraction of the time it will round up to `T(1.0)`.

When `T` is `float` (24 mantissa bits), we expect to see `uniform_real_distribution<float>(0,1)(g) == 1.0f` about 1 in 2^25 times. [My brute-force experimentation with libc++ confirms this expectation.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Culi50l3hCPLJMSD)

```
template<class F>
void test(long long N, const F& get_a_float) {
    int count = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        float f = get_a_float();
        if (f == 1.0f) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    printf("Expected %d '1.0' results; got %d in practice\n", (int)(N >> 25), count);
}

int main() {
    std::mt19937 g(std::random_device{}());
    auto N = (1uLL << 29);
    test(N, [&g]() { return std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(0,1)(g); });
    test(N, [&g]() { return std::generate_canonical<float, 32>(g); });
}
```

Example output:

```
Expected 16 '1.0' results; got 19 in practice
Expected 16 '1.0' results; got 11 in practice
```

When `T` is `double` (53 mantissa bits), we expect to see `uniform_real_distribution<double>(0,1)(g) == 1.0` about 1 in 2^54 times. I don't have the patience to test this expectation. :)

My understanding is that this behavior is fine. It may offend our sense of "half-open-rangeness" that a distribution claiming to return numbers "less than 1.0" can in fact return numbers that are *equal* to `1.0`; but those are two different meanings of "1.0", see? The first is the *mathematical* 1.0; the second is the IEEE single-precision floating-point number `1.0`. And we've been taught for decades not to compare floating-point numbers for exact equality.

Whatever algorithm you feed the random numbers into isn't going to care if it sometimes gets exactly `1.0`. There's nothing you can *do* with a floating-point number except mathematical operations, and as soon as you do some mathematical operation, your code will have to deal with rounding. Even if you *could* legitimately assume that `generate_canonical<float,1000>(g) != 1.0f`, you *still* wouldn't be able to assume that `generate_canonical<float,1000>(g) + 1.0f != 2.0f` — because of rounding. You just can't get away from it; so why would we pretend in this single instance that you can?

Comment: I strongly disagree with this view. If the standard dictates values from a half-open interval and an implementation breaks this rule, the implementation is wrong. Unfortunately, as ecatmur correctly pointed out in his answer, the standard also dictates the algorithm which has a bug. This is also officially recognized here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2524

Comment: @cschwan: My interpretation is that the implementation *is not* breaking the rule. The standard dictates values from [0,1); the implementation returns values from [0,1); some of those values happen to round up to IEEE `1.0f` but that's just unavoidable when you cast them to IEEE floats. If you want pure mathematical results, use a symbolic computation system; if you are trying to use IEEE floating-point to represent numbers that are within `eps` of 1, you are in a state of sin.

Comment: Hypothetical example that would be broken by this bug: divide something by `canonical - 1.0f`.  For every representable float in `[0, 1.0)`, `x-1.0f` is non-zero.  With exactly 1.0f, you can get a divide-by-zero instead of just a very tiny divisor.