# How to determine the minimal noticable change of a double

Tags: floating-point

I have the problem to determine the smallest value `eps` for a given double variable `v` such that

```
v+eps != v
```

Note that this is not the typical problem sheet task since `eps` depends on the arbitrary
number `v`.

This should not be done by seeking this value in a for loop. Is there a fast way to do this,
e.g. by bit shifting? Independent of the compiler, optimization flags, platform...

Thanks for your answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find nearest next/previous double value (numeric\_limits::epsilon for given number)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160079/how-to-find-nearest-next-previous-double-value-numeric-limitsepsilon-for-give)

Comment: @BoBTFish and also completely besides the question.

Comment: @rubenvb Yes, I started writing it, then couldn't quite get my head around what I meant about turning that into an epsilon. So I went off to do some reading. I'll just delete it until such time as I work out what I'm trying to say.

Comment: The question and the title ask for different things. If d is the minimum change from (a positive) v to the next greater representable value and e is the smallest (positive) value such that calculating v+e does not produce v, then e is half d or very slightly greater, depending on the low bit of the significand of v. This is because, in floating-point arithmetic, a mathematical result just halfway to the next representable value is enough to cause rounding upward. (If it exactly halfway, rounding is down if the low bit of v is even, up if odd, which is why e may be slightly more than half d.)

Comment: You should specify clearly whether you want d or e and change the title and the question text to match. (Note: This assumes IEEE 754 arithmetic in the common round-to-nearest mode.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C99 function `nextafter` is what you need. Alternatively, use Boost.Math's `nextafter`. This is implementation defined by definition (it relies on the internal representation of `double` in memory).

For a comparison of all methods presented in the answers here at the time of writing, see [a live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f6fe629a258295d) to see how the other solutions fail.

---

For reference, here is the test code if you want to run it on our own system:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cfloat>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
#include <iomanip>
using std::setprecision;

#include <boost/math/special_functions/next.hpp>

double
epsFor( double x )
{
  union
  {
    double d;
    unsigned long long i;
  } tmp;
  tmp.d = x;
  ++ tmp.i;
  return tmp.d - x;
}

void test(double d)
{
  double d1 = std::nextafter(d,DBL_MAX);
  double d2 = d+std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() * d;
  double d3 = d+epsFor(d);
  double d4 = boost::math::nextafter(d, DBL_MAX);
  cout << setprecision(40)
       << "For value of d = " << d << '\n'
       << " std::nextafter: " << d1 << '\n'
       << " Boost solution: " << d4 << '\n'
       << " undefined beh.: " << d3 << '\n'
       << " numeric_limits: " << d2 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  test(0.1);
  test(986546357654.354687);
}
```

Comment: why the `*d` in `d+epsFor(d)*d`?

Comment: @henrik because Ivan's answer does that.

Comment: well, no, Ivan's answer uses epsilon, not epsFor.

Comment: What if the mantissa addition (You are adding +1 to the number, so its added on the mantissa [the lsb zone]) results in an overflow? It modifies the exponent. And so one (The overflow could be propagated to the msb zone, modifying the exponent, the sign after that, etc).

Comment: @Manu343726 With IEEE floating point, the results will still be correct.  (There would be a problem, of course, if the overflow resulted in Inf.)

Comment: @JamesKanze the overflow results in `exponent += 1` and `mantissa := 000000000` right? It should be `exponent += 1` and `mantissa := 0000001`, isn't?

Comment: Actually, my `espFor` gives exactly the same results as `boost::nextafter`.  The "live demo" which is linked to seems to show rather a bug in the compiler (or a misuse of the expressions---C++ is very lax with regards to the precision of the intermediate results).

Comment: Of course, the `boost::nextafter` or `std::nextafter`, if available, is preferable, because they handle all of the border cases (0, underflow, overflow, etc.) correctly.

Comment: @James, no, as Henrik pointed out, I made a mistake, it is now corrected and your code does indeed give the same as the `nextafter` solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use type punning:

```
double
epsFor( double x )
{
    union
    {
        double d;
        unsigned long long i;
    } tmp;
    tmp.d = x;
    ++ tmp.i;
    double results = tmp.d - x;
    return results;
}
```

(Formally, this is undefined behavior, but in practice, I don't
know of a modern compiler where it will fail.)

EDIT:

Note that C++ allows excessive precision in intermediate
expressions; since we're concerned here with exact results, the
originally posted function could give wrong results if you used
it directly in an expression, rather than assigning it to
a `double`.  I've added an assignment in the function to avoid
this, but be aware that a lot of compilers are *not* standard
conform in this regard, at least by default.  (g++ is a good
example of one where you need a special option to have
conformant behavior, at least when optimization is turned on.
If you're using g++, you must specify the
`-ffloat-store` option if you want correct results.)

Comment: Do you know of any guarantee with respect to the size of `i`? Wouldn't it be safer to use ``uint64_t``?

Comment: This will return negative values if x is negative. Not sure, if that's what the OP wants. +1 anyway.

Comment: Definitely going to downvote for the undefined behaviour. You can set optimization flags in GCC and Clang that will break this.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Any use of this is clearly implementation dependent.  I used the appropriate types for the most common platforms (Intel and AMD, Sparc, Power PC, etc.).  In this case, I'm not sure `unint64_t` would buy anything: it will cause the compile to fail on a few exotic platforms (Unisys mainframes, for example), which might be an advantage.  (Or not.  I don't know what `long long` is on those platforms, and it may be that using `uint64_t` would cause compilation to fail although the above would work.)

Comment: @DeadMG G++ has always guaranteed this in the past.  You can work around the undefined behavior using `memcpy` if you wish; the "intent" of the standard is that type punning should work with `reinterpret_cast`, but in fact, g++ only guarantees it with the `union` (which is the most widespread way of accomplishing it).  And since the above is clearly only valid for IEEE (and similar representations which use an implicit MSB in the mantissa), I'm only worried about what really happens in actual practice.

Comment: `-ffloat-store` does not entirely fix the issue with higher-precision intermediate results, as it causes double-rounding instead. The solution is to embrace higher-precision and make it part of the definition of the language's semantics. This is what the C99 compiler-defined FLT_EVAL_METHOD is for. Recent C++ standards also define FLT_EVAL_METHOD, with the same meaning as in C.

Comment: @PascalCuoq `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` doesn't really help here, since I can't control it.  And none of the standard defined values seem to correspond to what g++ actually does (nor with some options, what VC++ does).

Comment: @JamesKanze Do recent g++ versions accept the `-fexcess-precision=standard` flag? I understand http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2008-11/msg00105.html as meaning that recent a g++ should understand it. (Note: I am aware that we are getting sidetracked here slightly, but we are on-topic in the sense that `-fexcess-precision=standard`, if accepted, should make g++ drop excess precision on assignments, something you refer to in your answer)

Comment: @PascalCuoq I haven't verified.  The _documentation_ says that `-fexcess-precions` only applies to C, which would mean not to C++.  But it would definitely make sense in C++ as well.

Comment: May I suggest you try the program in section “A ray of hope” in http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/24/More-on-FLT_EVAL_METHOD_2 with `g++ -fexcess-precision=standard`? It is impossible in theory to disprove the assertion “the compiler does whatever it pleases with floating-point computations”, but in practice, when GCC or Clang are breaking the semantics suggested by the standard, they break them badly.

Comment: I get “cc1plus: sorry, unimplemented: -fexcess-precision=standard for C++” with SVN GCC snapshot 172652, the most recent g++ I have around, from 2011-04-18.

Answer (score 0):

```
eps = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() * v;
```

Comment: Not actually the correct answer here, thanks to rounding... v + v*eps*(2/3), for instance.

Comment: That is the difference between `1.0` and the next representable `double`. The gap will be larger for larger `double`s

Comment: @BoBTFish : epsilon() is, that's why you should multiply it with v.

Comment: The gap is not linearly increasing.

Comment: @DeadMG Considering that the OP does not know whether he wants ULP(v) or half of it, I find this answer good enough. `v * (1 + epsilon) - v` computes the ULP half the times without using nextafter() or type-punning, but half the times it evaluates to 2ULPs. Perhaps something like `v + (v * epsilon / 2) - v` can be made to work in all cases, but as written I still fear it is wrong on some cases.